# Getting error when trying to implement site-wide breadcrumbs in Twentytwentyone Theme

Tags: php, themes, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, breadcrumb

I've purchased the Yoast SEO Premium plugin earlier this year, but I wasn't able to figure out how to enable breadcrumbs until a few days ago. At first I thought I had to add blocks to every page and post, and I thought that would be incredibly tedious, until I found this [article](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-add-breadcrumbs-to-your-wordpress-website#:%7E:text=To%20do%20this%2C%20go%20to,settings%20according%20to%20your%20needs.).

Since I was already using the Twentytwentyone theme, I decided to add the code to its `header.php` file.

```php
<?php
if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
  yoast_breadcrumb( '<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>' );
}
?>
```

When I went to reload the site to see if the breadcrumbs showed up, I got a critical error, so I went into my log and saw this error.

> [Sun Oct 03 02:32:59.026295 2021] [php7:error] [pid 8225] [client 172.68.133.221:44594] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function \xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0yoast_breadcrumb() in /var/www/html/sensation-experience.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/header.php:35\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/sensation-experience.com/public_html/wp-includes/template.php(770): require_once()\n#1 /var/www/html/sensation-experience.com/public_html/wp-includes/template.php(716): load_template('/var/www/html/s...', true, Array)\n#2 /var/www/html/sensation-experience.com/public_html/wp-includes/general-template.php(48): locate_template(Array, true, true, Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/sensation-experience.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/page.php(12): get_header()\n#4 /var/www/html/sensation-experience.com/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/var/www/html/s...')\n#5 /var/www/html/sensation-experience.com/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/var/www/html/s...')\n#6 /var/www/html/sensation-experience.com/public_html/index.php(17): require('/var/www/html/s...')\n#7 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/sensation-experience.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/header.php on line 35, referer: https://www.sensation-experience.com/

From what it looks like, there seems to be something going on between the Yoast plugin and the theme, but I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: How did you add the code? because I just tested it on a clean WordPress install with yoast and it works great. Seems like you copied some unwanted characters, `\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0`, try manualy writing the function with the if condition, not copy paste it

Comment: I figured out what happened. When I copied it, I evidently used some &nbsp; characters, which has a different ASCII value. I'd still like to keep this question open once I do enough research to post an answer about why a nonbreaking space might interfere with the coding.

Comment: This sometimes happens when copying from websites, because usualy they have some libarary that displays the code visually and sometimes it adds spaces as ascii values, when that happens I usually write the code manualy or paste it into notepad and then copy it.

Comment: That makes sense. I am completely blind and use a screen reader, but it was able to tell me that the whitespaces around it were different from a regular space.

Comment: Amazing that screen readers can tell the difference, will take that into account from now on, always happy to make the internat more accessible to everyone, even when it means paying attention to ascii spaces from actual spaces. Cheers!

Comment: This is a very important subject and I hope this will get more attention, we as developers should do the max to make our code/products accessible to everyone, bookmarked this question and upvoted it, hope this will help getting more peoples attention!